# crontab permission with python cgi

Tags: python, cron, cgi

I want to use python's crontab lib to interact with crontab mission.
If I write code into a python file, let's call it cron.py:

```
from crontab import CronTab
my_cron = CronTab(user=True)
job = my_cron.new(command='python test.py')
job.minute.every(1)
my_cron.write()
```

and run:

```
python cron.py
```

I will get “Terminal” would like to administer your computer. Administration can include modifying passwords, networking, and system settings. After I allow it, the crontab mission can be successfully added.However if I write the same code into a python cgi file, and want to use a html page to trigger it(for example, in html page I click a button, then the cgi script will be triggered), I will get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chuci/apa/CGI-Executables/create.py", line 58, in <module>
    my_cron.write()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crontab.py", line 354, in write
    CRONCMD, ret, proc.stderr.read()))
OSError: Program Error: /usr/bin/crontab returned 1: b'crontab: tmp/tmp.8166: Operation not permitted\n'
```

So I wonder what should I do to deal with this permission problem? I'm using macOS and apache2 for web server and cgi. I have already run 'chmod 777 create.py' for my cgi file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After I consult the developer of the crontab library, here is his reply:

*Thanks for reporting the issue.
You are the first person I think who has reported using the module with macOS. As a UNIX it should be compatible though since it's crontab isn't very complicated.
The permissions error you've reported is consistent with not running as root. I don't know why mac would need extra permissions to write to a user's crontab, I suspect it has a lot to do with their permissions system, but I have no idea how that might work.
If you find out what the issue is, I'd welcome a patch to improve mac support.*

So the solution is: use it on Unix instead of macOS. macOS may has some security check which will make it failed.